# Continuous data protection in a datacentre

Tags: apache-2.2, backup-restoration, cdp, backup

2 1u servers in a datacentre, 1 pc in an office for offsite backup.

was wondering the best way to backup data onsite for one of those 2 servers (the other ones data isnt as important)

the backups would need to be as close to real time as possible.

so i read about CDP and was wondering is this the best method for it and if it is, how should i do it and what tools would i need?

Comment: What OS? What are you using for backups now? Do you need truly continuous data mirroring, or do you just want it backed up frequently? What kind of applications/data are being backed up, and what software is storing that data? How often/much does the data change? What's your budget? What are your data recovery goals? What kind of downtime can you tolerate? You're missing a lot of details.

Comment: Jamie, I know you're from Kent and all :) but you can do a better job of writing this question, please try to tidy it up and add a LOT more details.

Comment: not a bad question, but woefully lacking in detail

Answer (score 1):

[DBRD](http://www.drbd.org/)

Comment: Note to op: This is only goodfor *nix